# Is it a bad idea to add myself to the sudo group?

Tags: debian, security, sudo, password, group

Members of the `sudo` group in my Debian install can execute anything without entering a password. This is convenient, but seems like a bad idea.

**NOTE:** My computer is an ordinary desktop, not a server or something like that.

Should I disable this or is it safe?

Bonus points for explaining what could happen (i.e. possible attack vectors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sudo` command is configured by `/etc/sudoers`.

This should contain a line like:

```
 %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

This allows all members of the sudo group to allow arbitrary commands (on any host as any user).

It requires you to enter your own password unless the line includes the `NOPASSWD:` part.

---

You need some way to to administrative tasks like installing new software. The two main ways are either explicitly logging in as root with a dedicated root password or using a privileged user which is allowed to use `sudo` to do so.

Having `NOPASSWD:` active is sometimes convenient, but might be dangerous for a everyday account as even scripts can use `sudo` without any feedback to you.

Without `NOPASSWD:`, `sudo` will ask for your own password. This requires you to explicitly acknowledge the command and is a good setting for an everyday account. The only weak point is, that the confirmation is cached for some times, which might be exploited from someone else getting access to your terminal just after you did some sudo thing.

---

The "right" configuration depends a bit on your situation, but I usually set up a host completely without a root password. This way the only way to do root things is logging in as a regular (personalized!) user and doing sudo.

This way you have lots of control. If multiple persons should be allowed root permissions just add those to the sudo group. Afterwards you can see in the log file who issued which root command at which time. You can even specify which user is allowed to execute which command and much more.

Comment: While this is a good answer, don't forget this "Afterwards you can see in the log file who issued which root command at which time" is not necessarily true.  Once person X is root, person X can hide all of their activity before and while being root, unless you have off-server logging.  At worst they'll be able to leave a hole so you can't be sure who did what.

Comment: And it's possible for a user to accidentally cover their sudo tracks as well. A web developer on a machine I managed once typed "sudo rm -rf /var/ www/somedir/" instead of "sudo rm /var/www/somedir", blowing away server logs and every thing else in /var. The machine was easily restored from a backup, but became good ammunition against giving developers sudo access on production machines when they asked for it periodically.

Comment: If you give root permissions to some malicious user you already lost. (You can even run something harmless like `less` and spawn a new root shell from it.) The logging part is only for reference not for security.  - The only relevant security thing are other people getting access to your terminal or (potential) malicious commands/script you run.

Comment: @michas that was my point, I was just making it clear.